# I am working on a spring and hibernate web application MySQLDialect not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-jdbc

When i deploy it shows following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.quad.dao.RoleDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

but i have hibernate jar file in lib folder.I dont understand why it is giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have your hibernate jar file in your classpath. Add the jars to your classpath and do a clean build.